# Getting "Failed to compile" error while executing the React application with ThreeJS and React three fiber

Tags: reactjs, three.js, gltf, react-three-fiber

I'm using the following code -

```
import React, { Suspense, useRef, useState, useEffect } from "react"
import { Canvas } from "react-three-fiber"
import { useGLTF } from "@react-three/drei/core"
import { OrbitControls } from "drei"

function Model(props) {
  const group = useRef()
  const { nodes, materials } = useGLTF('newmodel.glb')
  return (
    <group ref={group} {...props} dispose={null}>
      <mesh material={materials.lambert129} geometry={nodes.table_1.geometry} />
      <mesh material={materials.blinn6} geometry={nodes.table_2.geometry} />
      <mesh material={materials.lambert54} geometry={nodes.polySurface2862_1.geometry} />
      <mesh material={materials.lambert55} geometry={nodes.polySurface2862_2.geometry} />
      <mesh material={materials.lambert62} geometry={nodes.polySurface2862_3.geometry} />
      <mesh material={materials.lambert54} geometry={nodes.group36_1.geometry} />
      <mesh material={materials.phong339} geometry={nodes.group36_2.geometry} />
      <mesh material={materials.lambert55} geometry={nodes.group36_3.geometry} />
      <mesh material={materials.lambert58} geometry={nodes.group36_4.geometry} />
      <mesh material={materials.lambert63} geometry={nodes.group36_5.geometry} />
      <mesh material={materials.lambert61} geometry={nodes.group36_6.geometry} />
      <mesh material={materials.lambert60} geometry={nodes.group36_7.geometry} />
    </group>
  )
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Canvas style={{height:500,width:700}}>
        <ambientLight intensity={0.3} />
        <spotLight intensity={0.3} angle={0.1} penumbra={1} position={[5, 25, 20]} />
        <Suspense fallback={null}>
          <Model />
        </Suspense>
        <OrbitControls />
      </Canvas>
    </>
  )
}
```

**Error - Failed to compile.
./node_modules/drei/useSubdivision.js
Attempted import error: 'Geometry' is not exported from 'three'.**

I've tried multiple import methods but none of them are working, I've also tried switching the version of drei@2.2.21 three@0.125.0.
Please help!

Answer (score 0):

dependent on [issues/261](https://github.com/pmndrs/drei/issues/261)

> Geometry was removed from three@0.125.0 check the peer deps of the
> drei package you're  installing. If you want to use three@125 you need
> to use @react-three/drei at a minimum of 3.0.0

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved after doing some research and following the guidelines as posted by Babak.
For the solution, I'm using the following versions for the packages -

> @react-three/drei@3.0.0
> drei@2.2.17
> react-three-fiber@5.3.14
> three@0.124.0